# Exporting / Saving Pattern Swatches in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, swatches

I would like to keep the patterns I have created in Illustrator CS6 in a handy file. Currently, I just make an object, apply the pattern, and copy/paste the object to transfer the pattern to a different file, but would like to save all of the patterns so that I can just load them all at once. Is the Save Swatch Library as ASE the best way to do this? I want to be sure I can share these patterns with others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't save pattern swatches in ase format:

[image]

The best way to to this is to have an Illustrator file that you can simply paste a new pattern-filled shape to then save.

You can then share that .ai file and load it as an "Other Library" to import all the pattern swatches.

Comment: Thank you @scott, I was afraid there was not an easy way!

Comment: It actually is pretty easy. Create a new file and delete all swatches from it (symbols and graphic styles too to keep size down). Then save the file. if you set up a shortcut to this (pattern) file. Simply open, paste, save. Then when you need the patterns, load the file as a Library, same as you would for .ase files.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest/easiest way to do this in Mac OS X and Windows is simply;

1. Open the file with the original desired pattern you want to use
2. Be sure the "Brushes" palette window is displayed
3. Open a new/existing file you want to use said pattern
4. From the original file, click and drag the desired pattern, form the brushes palette, to the tab of the new file
5. Let the mouse hover for a moment and your pattern will appear in your new document